# Going "back" when using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, pdf, viewers, navigation

I'm including `\usepackage{hyperref}` so that each instance of `\ref` (as well as each page number in the index and the table of contents) automatically links to that page.

When I'm viewing the document (in [`Sumatra`](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html)) and I click a link, I jump to the linked page.  Is there any easy way to go "back" to where I was before I clicked the link?  (And is the answer any different when using Adobe Acrobat reader?)

Comment: Such a correspondence is usually "one to many": which place of the PDF should this point to? All the PDF viewers have a "go back" facility, AFAIK.

Comment: This depends on the PDF viewer - for Adobe Reader, you can find a solution in an answer to [How to return to original .pdf presentation after open a .pdf linked file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28603/3323).

Comment: This question is also asked at SuperUser ("[Back button of Adobe PDF Reader after clicking a hyperlink whose target is on the same document](http://superuser.com/questions/22786/back-button-of-adobe-pdf-reader-after-clicking-a-hyperlink-whose-target-is-on-th)").  Many PDF viewers, including Adobe Reader, use [ALT]+[Left Arrow].

Comment: An ability to go back was one of the two main reasons to switch to Skim.

Comment: Note for the ones coming from a search engine: If you are looking for how to back-reference an arbitrary thing like a listing or a figure, have a look at the question [„How to backreference floating environments like listings or figures to where they are mentioned?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558992/98645).
If you have this, people can click on that link to get back. :)

Comment: Better answer here: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Actually this has nothing to do with TeX …

There’s no default, so one needs to check the viewer’s menus and shortcuts, because each application can use its own method. However, on MS Windows the keys are the same for `Adobe Reader`, `SumatraPDF` and `PDF XChange Viewer` (and probably some others which I can’t test now): <kbd>Alt</kbd> plus left cursor key for “Go back to last view” and <kbd>Alt</kbd> plus right cursor key for “Go to next view”. The latter is only active, when the former at least once was used. Despite the same key association the different readers behave not exactly the same. Enrico Gregorio (egreg) reported, that on Mac OS X it's <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> (*except for Adobe Reader*).

Comment: Of course, this depends on the operating system and, possibly, on the language (at least on Mac OS X).

Comment: Something about: "one needs to check the viewer's menus and shortcuts because each application can use its own method". For example on Mac OS X it's Command+[ and Command+] (except for Adobe Reader).

Comment: Thank you, I was just looking for this! Really helpful, especially when you read something 1300-1400 pages long (like C++ language standard drafts) and at some place have multiple hyperlinks to places spread over the whole document.

Answer (score 10):

The PDF format also knows link annotations with named actions, which calls functions of the PDF viewer. The official list of these named actions in the PDF specification for version 1.7 (ISO standard version) is quite short:

- `NextPage`, `PrevPage`
- `FirstPage`, `LastPage`

However, the list supported by AcrobatReader is much longer. Section "5 Acrobat-specific behavior" of the `hyperref` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) lists some more named actions, among them:

- `GoBack`, `GoForward`

The `GoBack` action is of interest here. With macro

```
\Acrobatmenu{<action name>}{<free text>}
```

a link for going back can be set, for example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[variablett]{lmodern}

\newcommand*{\Button}[1]{%
  \Acrobatmenu{#1}{\fbox{\texttt{#1}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\Navigation}{%
  \begin{center}
    \Button{FirstPage}\qquad
    \Button{LastPage}\\
    \Button{PrevPage}\qquad
    \Button{NextPage}\\ 
    \Button{GoBack}\qquad
    \Button{GoForward}
  \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Navigation
  \section{Document start}
  \lipsum[1-3]
  \Navigation
  \section{Last section}
  \lipsum[4]
  \Navigation
\end{document}
```

Of course, it depends on the PDF viewer, whether actions and which actions are aupported. AR should work, xpdf 3.03 knows the actions of the test file above.
Evince 3.4.0 only knows the actions from the PDF specification, but not `GoBack` or `GoForward`.

Comment: How can I make the buttons appear at the bottom of the page and going horizontally?

Comment: +1: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what others said: This back functionality has nothing to do with TeX because you wouldn't encode the back link (from the link destination back to the link source) in the PDF document itself.  Rather, the functionality is built into the PDF viewer; when you click a link, taking you to a different page in the PDF document, the PDF viewer remembers where you were and can take you back if you press the right 'back' button. As egreg pointed out, it's common to have many links to the same place so it wouldn't be clear where the back links should point.

Wikipedia is somewhat of an exception in that some link destinations (such as Note #2 [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_frontier#Notes)) have a list of *all* the link sources in the entire document.  For Wikipedia, they are labeled with lowercase letters ('a', 'b', ...), and you can just click them one-by-one to see ever place in the main text that references a particular note.  I don't know if PDFs support this functionality or, if they do, whether you can create such a PDF with TeX .

Answer (score 3):

For the evince PDF viewer it is not so easy to find how to add this functionality.
A solution involving the "back" button can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/330105/document-viewer-evince-history-navigation).

I had to add the icon for "back" (which is a left arrow) to the toolbar as described above. Note that "back" means "previous viewed page" and not "previous page" which is denoted by the up-arrow icon.