# How to go back to body after visiting a reference?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, links

I am a big fan of `hyperref`. It allows (among other things) to go quickly to the bibliography (at the end of a document) by clicking to the name of the author in the body of the text. So, I have plenty of links which look like that:

[image]

If I click on `2000`, I could see what book is actually cited (in the bibliography). I do this a lot but I am always facing a issue for continuing reading. Indeed, I have to find the exact page where the citation was by hand...

*I'm wondering if there is a way to add a link (anchor) inside the bibliography in order to send back to the text body.*

Of course, the main (and huge) problem is to know where you were when you clicked on the citation and where to see you back. I cannot think a way to achieve this but I'm asking this question to collect idea on this subject.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@Book{author00:_title,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2000}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
     hyperref,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{author00:_title}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know whether this could be implemented using LaTeX. However, some pdf viewers (such as Adobe Reader or Foxit Reader) feature a keyboard shortcut for that purpose (Alt+Left Arrow in the above cases).

Comment: There is [no way to have a universal "go back" link, I don't think](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51320/35864) (I'd have thought there might be some JavaScript hack specific to AdobeReader, but couldn't find anything more). But you can have back-references in the bibliography that link back to where the items in the bibliography were cited. Just add the option `backref` to `biblatex` at loading time.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to implement this in LaTeX: A destination can have more then one source. Use the means of your pdf viewer to go back as you would do it in a brower.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer has a point there, if I remember correctly from my HTML days (they were quite some time ago), there is no HTML way to have such a back button: It could be implemented via JavaScript or PHP, but not HTML-native. So this feature does not seem to something that is available in markup languages that are normally agnostic with respect to how someone got to a specific part of the output.

Comment: I use features of the PDF viewers (Preview View and Next View in Foxit Reader; Preview view and Next view in Adobe Reader). Several times, I tried and used the `authorindex` tool to enhance my document. This tool adds a list of pages, where a specific reference is cited in the document, at the very end of a bibliography item. Still, if you want to use it and a reference is cited multiply times, you shall have a general idea which page you were reading before clicking a hyperlink.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know a destination can have more than one source. This is "the main (and huge) problem" I mentioned.

Comment: @moewe Sorry for `\usebibresource` I was using `\bibliography` and change that, making a mistake, before posting to avoid annoying remarks about obsoleteness. But I'm sure you know also that you could have corrected my mistake instead of just pointing it... :-)

Comment: It certainly wasn't a big deal. Normally I avoid changing people's code, because I can never be sure about the intentions behind posting that exact code and in a way I think it often constitutes "changing the message of the post". In this case, though where it was quite obvious that this had nothing to do with the issue, it wouldn't have done any harm, I admit.

Comment: Talking about specific PDF readers, in Zathura the "back" feature is `Ctrl-O` (same as Vim).

Answer (score 11):

Each not too bad PDF viewer should have a "back" feature for jumping to the previous location. Thus there is no need to have such a go back link.

Nevertheless there are some options:

### `backref`

Package `biblatex` provides a `backref` feature, which prints a list of pages, where the bibliography entry is cited. Of course the user would have to remember the page.

### `GoBack` menu option

The PDF format knows named link actions like `PrevPage`, `NextPage`, `First`, and `Last`. AR and some PDF viewers also know additional named actions like `GoBack`. Package `hyperref` provides `\Acrobatmenu` to specify such links.

Example, which replaces the list of back references in `biblatex` by such a generic `GoBack` link:

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@Book{author00:_title,
  author =   {Author},
  title =    {Title},
  publisher =    {Publisher},
  year =     2000}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,
     hyperref]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \Acrobatmenu{GoBack}{Go back}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\cite{author00:_title}

\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result bibliography]

Comment: This works very well with Adobe Reader and SumatraPDF, but failed with TeXworks' built-in reader.

Comment: While we are at it, do you think an answer employing much the same method would benefit [Going “back” when using hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51320/35864)? It is one of the first questions that comes up when searching for going back from links.

Comment: @moewe Yes, hood idea. I have now provided an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238478/16967) there.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same thing with bibtex ?