# Beamer: make some slides inaccessible for usual navigation

Tags: beamer, navigation

Is there a way to make some slides inaccessible for basic forward navigation controls (left arrow and mouse click)? Motivation: I want these slides to reside at the end of my presentation and be accessible only via hyperlinks. According to [Beamer User Guide](http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) this might be possible w/ `\lecture` and `\includeonlylecture` but this accomplished nothing (a MWE below). Another solution would be to somehow<sup>†</sup> specify the current slide to be the next one shown (and put the reserved stuff after it), but I don't know if this is possible. A third way would be to make the reserved slides be partly like the last and partly new, and switch the shown/hidden parts depending on whether a link is clicked or not. As I'm running out of time in preparing the presentation, I will not start experimenting w/ any of this

<sub><sup>†</sup> E.g. by a label or option</sub>

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\includeonlylecture{wee1}

\begin{document}

\lecture{Vector Spaces}{wee1}
\frame{ju}
\frame{ju0}

\lecture{Scalar Products}{wee2}
\frame{nu}
\frame{nu0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about a fourth way: produce two documents, and upon a click on some button, the second document opens?

Comment: Good. But then I need to get back to a specific remembered frame in the first. You might make this into an answer

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413375/121799) and see if this does the job for you. Otherwise: going back to the remembered frame may not be necessary if you just open an additional window in full screen mode upon the click, which you close when you're done.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You can move a slide to the end with

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\frame<1-2>[label=myframe]
{
\begin{itemize}
\item<alert@1> First subject.
\item<alert@2> Second subject.
\item<alert@3> Third subject.
\end{itemize}
}
\frame
{
Some stuff explaining more on the second matter.
}
\againframe<3>{myframe}
\end{document}
```

But it will still reach it with the standard keys. I don't think that it is possible to forbid a pdf reader to go to a page in a pdf. If you really want this you would need an additional document or an embedded pdf.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal in the comments fleshed out, following the directions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28193/121799) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28603/121799). Create two files:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Vector spaces}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
Vector spaces are, as the name says, vector spaces. 

It is more fun to play with \href[pdfnewwindow]{DuckSlides.pdf}{ducks}.
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Second file: `DuckSlides.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Ducks}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\tikz{\duck}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compile both files and make sure that you adjust the permissions of `DuckSlides.pdf`, for instance by issuing `chmod 640 DuckSlides.pdf` on Linux or Mac OS. (Double-check that the permissions work.)

If you then click on "ducks" in the first presentation, a second presentation will open which you can simply close when you're done.